# Unable to filter events with specific values of indexed parameters

Tags: web3js, truffle, events, truffle-test, filters

I am currently trying to test a smart contract using the truffle suit ( with 'truffle test'). My contract is of a simple ERC20 token which includes the standard Transfer event:

```
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
```

Below is my code which attempts to subscribe to all "Transfer" events only coming from account[0] to account[1]. Even though the 2 parameters are declared as "indexed", the filter does not seem to work and I get all Transfer events no matter the sender/receiver. I tried modifying the code in various ways but nothing seems to work so far

```js
const EnergyToken = artifacts.require("EnergyToken");
const assert = require('assert');
const truffleAssert = require('truffle-assertions');
const { performance } = require('perf_hooks');

contract("Energy Heavy Load Test", async accounts => {
    const numberOfTransactions = 10;
    let startTime = 0;
    let finishTime = 0;
    let subscription;
    let contract;
    let i = 0;

    console.log(web3.version);

    // Function for rounding numbers
    function round(value, precision) {
        var multiplier = Math.pow(10, precision || 0);
        return Math.round(value * multiplier) / multiplier; 
    }

    // executed before each test
    before(async () => {
        contract = await EnergyToken.at("0x5BbD383bD43aC3896B86207eFe88cf0628ad06F0");
    });

    // Test mining time of 2500 transaction calls on the EnergyToken smart contract's transfer() method 
    it("send " + numberOfTransactions + " transactions of 1 EnergyToken from account 0 to account 1", (done) => {
        // contract.Transfer(function(error, event) { 
        //     i++;
        //     console.log(event)
        //     if(i == 1)
        //         startTime = performance.now();

        //     if (i == numberOfTransactions) {
        //         finishTime = performance.now();
        //         console.log("Transactions confirmed!" + " It took " + round((finishTime - startTime)/1000,2) + " seconds to confirm " + numberOfTransactions + " transactions");
        // .       done();
        //     }
        // });

        // contract.getPastEvents('Transfer', {
        //     filter: { from: accounts[0], to: accounts[1] },
        //     fromBlock: 0,
        //     toBlock: 'latest'
        // }, function(error, result) {
        //     if(error) {
        //         console.log(error, 'error');
        //     } else {
        //         console.log(result, 'result');
        //     }
        // });

        for (let j = 0; j < numberOfTransactions; j++) {
            contract.transfer(accounts[0], 1, { from:accounts[1] });
        }
        console.log("Finished sending " + numberOfTransactions + " transactions from account 1!!" + accounts[1] + " to "  + accounts[0]);
    });

    it("Calculate average gas used by the transfer() function", async () => {
        let result = await contract.transfer(accounts[1], 1);  
        let hash = await result.tx;
        let tx = await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash);
        let gasUsed = await tx.gasUsed;
        console.log(" Gas used for a 'Transfer' transaction: " + gasUsed);
    });

    it("Calculate average gas used by the approve() function", async () => {       
        let result = await contract.approve(accounts[1], 1000);  
        let hash = await result.tx;
        let tx = await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash);
        let gasUsed = await tx.gasUsed;
        console.log(" Gas used for an 'Approve' transaction: " + gasUsed);
    }); 

    it("Calculate average gas used by the transferFrom() function", async () => {
        await contract.approve(accounts[1], 100, { from: accounts[0] });  
        let result = await contract.transferFrom(accounts[0], accounts[1], 100, { from: accounts[1] });  
        let hash = await result.tx;
        let tx = await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(hash);
        let gasUsed = await tx.gasUsed;
        console.log(" Gas used for an 'Approve' transaction: " + gasUsed);
    });
});
```

Note: My version of web3 is 1.2.6

Comment: If your "web3 is 1.2.6" as you say it is, then you should by the least use `contract.events.Transfer` instead of `contract.Transfer`. The fact that your code runs and even fetches events, leads me to the logical conclusion that your web3 version is 0.x. In order to verify this, please run `console.log(web3.version)` in your program. And after verifying this, please refer to [the official documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-events) of that specific version. Side note: if you're on Truffle 4.x, then the web3 used inside your Truffle tests IS 0.x.

Comment: @goodvibration Thanks for the quick reply. My truffle version is Truffle v5.1.9 and I ran the code to check the web3 version - it is 1.2.1. I read the documentation earlier and indeed it says I should use contract.events.Transfer but contract.events returns undefined for some reason. That's why tried changing the code a bit and using contract.Transfer I managed to at least get some events back. No luck in trying to filter them so far though.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should check your web3 version again by running in the terminal `npm view web3 version` in the root of your project. And then again you can check the version in the javascript by doing `console.log(web3.version);`. If it's really 1.x.x then you should be able to filter the events like this:

```
contract.getPastEvents('Transfer', {
    filter: {'from': accounts[0], 'to': accounts[1]},
    fromBlock: 0,
    toBlock: 'latest'
}, function(error, result) {
    if(error) {
        console.log(error, 'error');
    } else {
        console.log(result, 'result');
    }
});
```

It's also not normal behavior `contract.events` to return null for web3 1.x.x. Here are the [docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-events) how web3 1.x.x is dealing with events. If the problem still appears post your smart contract code here so we can test.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I run npm view web3, the version is 1.2.6. However, using console.log(web3.version) in my truffle test code it says 1.2.1 (could be something related to truffle). As for contract.events, I am not sure why it returns undefined. When I run EnergyToken.events it returns the list of events. However,  when I assign the contract instance to a variable with :
  let  contract = await EnergyToken.at("0x5BbD383bD43aC3896B86207eFe88cf0628ad06F0");  then contract.events is undefined. According to the documentation, this should work in both versions since they are 1.x.x

Comment: Please attach your whole javascript or at least the logic where you define the instance. Also you work locally or on some of the testnets?

Comment: I added my whole test code. The event filtering that I am trying to implement should go into the first it() clause. And yes I am running a private network of nodes using geth  and truffle for contract deployment/testing.

Comment: This is my truffle test JS file => https://pastebin.com/xAC44PpX. Please check it carefully and adapt it to your logic. Unfortunately the code you shared above looks broken. I tested my example just right now with web3 1.2.6 and it all went smoothly.